# Кнопки и функции Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, menu

Я делал меню, просмотрел много туториалов и видео, но столкнулся с проблемой:
Я добавил несколько кнопок в *Canvas* и попытался повесить пару функций на кнопки, но после добавление скрипта кнопки не нажимаются. Исходный код:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class main_menu : MonoBehaviour

{

   public void Start1()
   {
     SceneManager.LoadScene("Part1");
     Grid easy = new Grid( 100, 10, 10);
   }

   public void Start2()
   {
      SceneManager.LoadScene("Part2");
      Grid Hard = new Grid(100, 10, 10);
   }
   public void Exit()
   {
      Application.Quit();
   }
}
```

Возможно что причина, по которой не нажимаются кнопки, другая?

Comment: После добавления скрипта куда? А на кнопках выбирали событие Onclick и привязывали тот самый объект со скриптом и его методами? Можете подробно описать как что куда присваивали? Можно даже со скринами))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предпочитаю привязывать листенеры как-нибудь так. Если не режет глаза, то можешь попробовать.

```
public class TestButtonScript : MonoBehaviour {
    private Button Button { get; set; }
    private void Start() {
        Button = GetComponent<Button>();
        Button.onClick.AddListener(() => { OnClick(); });
    }

    private void OnClick() {
        Debug.Log("Click");
    }
}
```

Comment: я разобралс, спасибо за помощь